# How do i minimise a Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Im trying to make the user use fullscreen then have the ability to minimise their screen, is there a way to do that in Tkinter?
this is my code for the main window

```
def home():
mainbody = Tk()  # main body
mainbody.geometry("1300x800")  # size of window
mainframe = Frame(mainbody)
mainframe.grid()
Button(mainframe, bg="RoyalBlue2", width=12, text="Desktop", command=desktop).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

and i want the user to be able to press "Desktop" which will minimise the window without to press a button to go back to full screen or atleast a larger size

```
def desktop():
goodbye_screen = Tk()
goodbye_screen.geometry("300x300")
Label(goodbye_screen, text="Goodbye!").grid()
goodbye_screen.withdraw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution I made for your problem. Also, I don't know if you intended to do this but if you keep on repeating `(variable) = Tk()`, the windows are going to conflict.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def desktop():
    Label(window, text="Goodbye!").grid()
    window.wm_state('iconic')

def home():
    window.geometry("1300x800")  # size of window
    mainframe = Frame(window)
    mainframe.grid()
    Button(mainframe, bg="RoyalBlue2", width=12, text="Desktop", command=desktop).grid(row=0, column=0)

home()
```

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` in GUI apps; it freezes the UI in a way that completely blocks all processing (including simple redrawing; the UI is totally frozen) while the sleep is occurring. In this case, what you really wanted was something like `window.after(500, window.wm_state, 'iconic')` which schedules the `window.wm_state('iconic')` call to occur 500 milliseconds later (while letting the event loop run normally in the meantime).

Comment: im getting this error"line 28, in home
    window.geometry("1300x800")  # size of window
NameError: name 'window' is not defined"
should i do desktop(window) to fix this?
and my intent is to create a mock hospital gui/app and if need be, have the user go to the desktop instead of having to quit the app

Comment: @NeoJoker26: You need to interpret it in the context of the rest of the code. `window` exists, if you define it globally like Jacob did (both functions see it in the global namespace without passing it around). Jacob used it instead of creating a new `Tk()` in each method because it's you usually only want/need one root window.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thanks for letting me know. I have edited the code, although it doesn't really need the delay